# parent-child data alignment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parent-child

I have this stored procedure that presents some inventory data and standard format and does not consider any parent-child relationship. This is the current view of the data along with many other columns:

I'm trying to bring the parent/child relationship in this report. so I've modified all the queries to bring in all parent/child data in. The data needs to be presented in a specific way. pic below:

[image]

Basically, need to list each parent first followed by all the child records. Then find these records for all child to display on the parent row.

```
the min of all child "1st Receipt Date", 
max of all child "Last Receipt Date", 
Sum of all child "On Hand"
Sum of all child "Sales Unit"
Mths Supply will be calculated from the total On Hand and Sales Units
```

[image]

I have no clue how to arrange the data in this manner. Would greatly appreciate some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm coming up with 160 in Sales Units.  Is this not a sum?  also how do you calculate #Mths Supply?

Comment: Scratch the 160 question, I had a typo,  The Months Supply question still stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- This Section is Just to Stage some Sample Data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @Inv table (SKU int,FirstReceiptDate Date,LastReceiptDate Date,OnHand int,SalesUnits int)
Insert Into @Inv (SKU,FirstReceiptDate,LastReceiptDate,OnHand,SalesUnits) values
(456,'2014-03-15','2014-12-14',0,15),
(789,'2014-05-30','2014-12-15',10,35),
(321,'2014-07-31','2016-03-16',112,60)

Declare @Hier table (SKU int,PtSKU int,PS int,Title varchar(50)) 
Insert into @Hier (SKU,PtSKU,PS,Title) values
(123,0,0,'SKU Tile 123'),
(456,123,10,'Some Other Title SKU 456'),
(789,123,20,'This is the Title for Title SKU 786'),
(321,123,30,'Finally Tile 321')


-- This Section Builds the Hierarchy with Range Keys  Hierarchies can be variable depth
-- My hierarchies are pretty static so they are rebuilt as needed
-- The real power is using the range key.  You can aggregate data without 
-- a recursive query.
-- I should not that I added a Presentation Sequence (PS) and Title to the Hierarcy
-- The PS is used to control the presentation order.  This can be alphabetical as well
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;With cteOH (SKU,PtSKU,Lvl,PS,SortSeq) as 
     (
        Select SKU,PtSKU,Lvl=1,PS,cast([dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](PS,0,6) +':' +[dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](SKU,0,6) + '/' as varchar(500)) from @Hier where  PtSKU=0
        Union All
        Select h.SKU,h.PtSKU,cteOH.Lvl+1,h.PS,SortSeq=cast(cteOH.SortSeq + [dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](H.PS,0,6) +':' +[dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](H.SKU,0,6) + '/' as varchar(500)) FROM @Hier h INNER JOIN cteOH ON  h.PtSKU = cteOH.SKU
     )
    ,cteR1  as (Select SKU,SortSeq,R1=Row_Number() over (Order by SortSeq) From cteOH)
    ,cteR2  as (Select A.SKU,R2 = max(B.R1) From cteOH A Join cteR1 B on (B.SortSeq Like A.SortSeq+'%') Group By A.SKU)
    Select B.R1
          ,C.R2
          ,A.Lvl
          ,A.SKU
          ,A.PtSKU
          ,A.PS
          ,T.Title
     Into  #TempOH
     From  cteOH A
     Join  cteR1 B on (A.SKU=B.SKU)
     Join  cteR2 C on (A.SKU=C.SKU)
     Join  @Hier T on (A.SKU=T.SKU)
     Order By B.R1


-- This Section illustrates how to aggregate data via the range keys
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select A.*  
      ,FirstReceiptDate       = min(B.FirstReceiptDate)
      ,LastReceiptDate        = max(B.LastReceiptDate)
      ,OnHand                 = sum(B.OnHand)
      ,SalesUnits             = sum(B.SalesUnits)
      ,MonthsSupply           = cast(sum(B.OnHand*12.)/sum(B.SalesUnits) as money)
      ,FamilyFirstReceiptDate = First_Value(min(B.FirstReceiptDate)) Over (Order By A.R1)
      ,FamilyLastReceiptDate  = First_Value(max(B.LastReceiptDate))  Over (Order By A.R1)
      ,FamilyOnHand           = First_Value(sum(B.OnHand))           Over (Order By A.R1)
      ,FamilySalesUnits       = First_Value(sum(B.SalesUnits))       Over (Order By A.R1)
      ,FamilyMonthsSupply     = First_Value(cast(sum(B.OnHand*12.)/sum(B.SalesUnits) as money))       Over (Order By A.R1)
 From #TempOH A
 Join (Select _R1=B.R1,A.* From @Inv A Join #TempOH B on A.SKU=B.SKU) B on _R1 between A.R1 and A.R2
 Group By A.R1,A.R2,A.Lvl,A.SKU,A.PtSKU,A.PS,A.Title
 Order By A.R1
```

Returns

```
R1                   R2                   Lvl         SKU         PtSKU       PS          Title                                              FirstReceiptDate LastReceiptDate OnHand      SalesUnits  MonthsSupply          FamilyFirstReceiptDate FamilyLastReceiptDate FamilyOnHand FamilySalesUnits FamilyMonthsSupply
-------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------- --------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------- ---------------------- --------------------- ------------ ---------------- ---------------------
1                    4                    1           123         0           0           SKU Tile 123                                       2014-03-15       2016-03-16      122         110         13.3091               2014-03-15             2016-03-16            122          110              13.3091
2                    2                    2           456         123         10          Some Other Title SKU 456                           2014-03-15       2014-12-14      0           15          0.00                  2014-03-15             2016-03-16            122          110              13.3091
3                    3                    2           789         123         20          This is the Title for Title SKU 786                2014-05-30       2014-12-15      10          35          3.4286                2014-03-15             2016-03-16            122          110              13.3091
4                    4                    2           321         123         30          Finally Tile 321                                   2014-07-31       2016-03-16      112         60          22.40                 2014-03-15             2016-03-16            122          110              13.3091
```

Required function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-PadL] (@Value varchar(50),@Pad varchar(10) = '0',@Len int = 10)

-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](25,0,10)
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-PadL](25,'-',6)

Returns varchar(50)
AS
  BEGIN
    Return right(concat(Replicate(@Pad,@Len),@Value),@Len)
  END
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response with a solution. Could you please explain this "[dbo].[udf-Str-PadL]" is that a function that you're calling?

Comment: My apologies.  I failed to include the function.   I will modify my answer to include the function.

Comment: Thanks for adding the function. My table structures look a bit different and have a very complex query that pulls the current data. What's the best way to show you what I have now including data?

Comment: Let's take it in smaller steps.  The thing to remember is that hierarchies are king.  The data to be aggregated is secondary, and we'll tackel that in a moment.    So my suggestion is show me your SKU structure with some sample data

Comment: Hi John, I added my sample table here with the current final query to get the resultset here: http://pastebin.com/rKHtMWQK I tried to explain some of the temp tables but if you have any questions about the data, please ask here and I'll respond right away. You'll see quite a few temp tables being used and I created few others to separate parent/child data from the non-parent/child items. My plan is to union once I obtain the dataset from two separate queries. you may see few fields that are not defined in the create script as they were not critical fields and some names may mismatch.

Comment: Great!  Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114548/discussion-between-eclipse-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: I pasted the sql in the chat window.   Not sure if you can retrieve after the fact.  I have it saved just in case

Comment: Hi John, You've been the most helpful and most knowledgeable and kind person I've met in this forum. Your solution works great and saved me a lot of headache. I just have one last question with this query, when I'm trying to union this and my existing query, running into an error.

Comment: Kind words.  Thank you,  What error are you getting?  Columns aligned?

Comment: are you able to join the chatroom? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114548/discussion-between-eclipse-and-john-cappelletti

Comment: I'm trying to use this query in sql server 2008 (separate test server for user testing) and the concat function that you used in your udf isn't available in 2008 R2. any suggestions?

Comment: That's a crime.   Let me open the chat to find where it is being used

Comment: In the PadL udf replace the return line with Return Right(Replicate(@Pad,@Len)+Ltrim(RTrim(@Value)),@Len)

Comment: Are you available for a quick chat? A little bit of confusion with the selection criteria.

Comment: Sure   I have 30 minutes until my next call.   Same chat window?  Opening now